# clicking div and moving one back and forth

Tags: jquery, css

i want to click a div and make another move to right:0 and if i click the div another time it will make the 2nd div move to right:-200 but i cant seem to get it workin.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#menu').click(function(){
        if ($('#menudrop').css('right', '-200px'));
            $('#menudrop').css('right', '0px');
        else{
            $('#menudrop').css('right', '-9999px');
        };
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/theUnderdog/woc6o12b/1/

Answer (score 0):

If condition was wrong use `$('#menudrop').css('right') == '-200px')`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#menu').click(function() {
    if ($('#menudrop').css('right') == '-200px')
      $('#menudrop').css('right', '0px');
    else {
      $('#menudrop').css('right', '-200px');
    };
  });
});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/woc6o12b/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simplified version :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#menu').click(function(){
    $('#menudrop').css('right', 
       $('#menudrop').css('right') == '-200px' ?  '0px' : '-200px');
  });
});
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/woc6o12b/4/